# How does WPML work with replace woocommerce messages?

Tags: string, woocommerce, cart, wpml

I'm running a WPML site with woocommerce and have replace some words in woocommerce with code such as:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function ( $message ) {

    $text = 'Product added to your cart.';

    return sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s',
        esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ),
        esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_html( $text )
    );

} );
```

(courtesy of Christopher, Thank you!)

My question is, how to I translate something like this?
I can only find in the strings the original text:
"%s has been added to your cart." and translating that does not work..

Is there any solutions?
I'd like to change the “%s has been added to your cart." text
while still keeping the "view cart" button there. (Also changed the text there)

Thanks in advance!

steve

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. What exactly do you want to translate?

If it's the value of `$text`, then you should wrap it with a [gettext function](https://wpml.org/documentation/support/enabling-text-translation-for-themes-not-compatible-with-wpml/), then use WPML's auto register strings for translation' functionality to find this string and translate it, because you're using a filter to modify the string (more on this below).

Before:

```
$text = 'Product added to your cart.';
```

After:

```
$text = __( 'Product added to your cart.', 'my-theme-domain' );
```

More info on how to use WPML's auto register strings for translation' functionality:

> In some cases, the static code-scan cannot reliably find all strings. This often happens when strings are generated dynamically using code.

https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/#auto-register-strings-for-translation